# $.ajax() data parameter order

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say my model looks like this:

```
public class someModel{
    public int age {get; set;}
    public string affiliation {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

And when I post from form `someForm`:

```
var request;
$('someForm').submit(function (event) {
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/addRecordResult',
            data: {
                affiliation: $('#affInput').val(),
                name: $('#nameInput').val(),
                age:$('#ageInput').val()
            },
            type: 'POST'
        });
```

in the `data` parameter in the Ajax method, does the order of inputs matter? Does it always have to be `age` then `affiliation` then `name`?

Comment: Nope. Order shouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "no", it doesn't matter